# navbarPage in Quarto doc is only vertical

Tags: r, shiny, quarto

When using the `navbarPage` layout to add a shiny app to a Quarto document the tab options always come out vertically, instead of horizontally. I would like them to be displayed horizontally. I.e. they are displayed like this

[Vertical Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7pxn.png)

But I would like them displayed like this

[Horizontal layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOAIV.png)

Here is a minimal reproducible example of my issue (run as a .qmd)

````
---
title: "navbarPage() Question"

format: html
server: shiny
editor: source
---

# Example 

```{r, echo=TRUE}
navbarPage(
  "Page title",
  tabPanel("panel 1", "one"),
  tabPanel("panel 2", "two"),
  tabPanel("panel 3", "three"),
  navbarMenu("subpanels", 
    tabPanel("panel 4a", "four-a"),
    tabPanel("panel 4b", "four-b"),
    tabPanel("panel 4c", "four-c")
  )
)
```

```{r}
#| context: server
```
````

I search for an option to toggle between the two (vertical and horizontal), but it seems like there isn't even a vertical option for shiny. All navbars are horizontal, so I'm not sure how this is happening.

I tried adjusting the arguments to `navbarPage`, such as `position`, `collapsible`, and `fluid`, and also

```
tags$head(tags$style('nav .container:first-child {
                           margin-left:10px; width: 100%;
                       }'))
```

and

```
tags$head(
           tags$style(HTML('.navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-brand {
                            padding-top:4px !important; 
                            padding-bottom:0 !important;
                            height: 25px;
                            }
                           .navbar {min-height:25px !important;}'))
         )
```

. But none of these made the layout horizontal.